Using Firefox, can I discover which website asset is making a network request?
I'm working on a local development version of a website built in php.
When the website is loaded, it makes network calls for assets hosted on an unrelated domain.
This domain no longer exists and the assets don't load. This doesn't seem to effect the website functionality, but the calls are unnecessary and they block - causing the website to load slower.
I haven't been able to find the call by using grep.
Is there a way to use Firefox's development tools to discover which component of the website is making the call?

In the Debugger tab, you can set breakpoints when the browser makes XMLHttpRequests.

You can break at any URL or filter based on method (GET, POST, PUT, etc.) and/or strings in the URL. Depending on how much code and how it's organized, it can still sometimes be challenging to locate the file. You may also have to trace the call up the stack to find the actual requesting procedure.
